# Why aren't all polynomial functions of odd degree, odd functions?

Tags: functions, polynomials

If it's an odd degree, why isn't it always an odd function? Can you please give me an example?

Comment: $x$ + 1 is not same as $-x$ +1

Comment: Because the degree of a polynomial refers only the highest order term, so polynomials of odd degree may contain lower order even powers which mess up the oddness. A polynomial with only odd powers of the variable would indeed be an odd function, but that's not what "odd degree" means.

Answer (score 1):

This is because to make $f(x)$ odd, it must satisfy $f(x) = -f(-x)$. Now in polynomials, if $f(x)$ is odd then it must have all the powers of variable odd.

We can prove this by showing that other cases where polynomial has atleast 1 even power does not satisfy.

Eg:
$f(x) = x + 1$

$f(-x) = -x + 1$

$f(x) ≠ -f(-x)$

Comment: The only function to satisfy $f(x)=-f(x)$ is $f(x)\equiv 0$

Comment: Fixed that, . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

An odd-degree mononomial is an odd function. A polynomial is an odd function if every one of its trms is of odd degree. Thus $$x^{17} +5ox^9-35x$$ is an odd function. But the degree of a polynomial is defined to be the degree of the term of highest degree, the so-called leading term, so $$3x^3+5x^2$$ is of odd degree because its leading term has degree 3, but the presence of a term of even degree prevents the polynomial from being an odd function.

Comment: So, to clarify, 2x^21+5x^5+x^4, is an even function? I'm just using an example.

Comment: No-for a polynomial to be an even function, all the powers would have to be even. Your polynomial has some powers that are odd and some powers that are even, so it is neither an even function nor an odd function.